# UDP data not read correctly (delayed)

Tags: wireshark, c++, udp, sockets

I have a server running on a Windows 7 desktop PC, and a client running on a Windows XP Lenovo laptop.

The following keeps happening in a loop:

- The client is broadcasting UDP packets containing some ID info.
- The server gets the broadcast and replies with another UDP packet with some data inside.

I can see in Wireshark that the server is sending the proper data, but the `RECVFROM` function is returning some other data. After around 20-30 seconds the data is finally read correctly.

If I run both the server and client on the desktop it works fine. Any ideas?

---

Relevant piece of code:

```
do
    {
       result=recvfrom(_socket,buff,buffLen,0,(SOCKADDR*)&SenderAddr,&SenderAddrSize);
       if(result != SOCKET_ERROR)
       {
          //small processing
          .....
         ////
         sendto(_socket,buff,16,0,(SOCKADDR*)&SenderAddr,sizeof(SenderAddr));
       } 
    while(true)
```

Comment: I guess it isn't an endianess problem, now is it?

Comment: doesn't look like because after around 20 seconds the data comes correctly....and in wireshark the data is correct all the time...very weird.

Comment: Another hint might be that...after I close the server...the client still gets UDP packet for a while :D

Comment: @todda May be a socket issue, so rather something for Windows

Comment: Could it be some other application is sending broadcast packets on the same port, by coincidence?  You might try sending/receiving on a different port to check...

Comment: Do you always send 16 bytes from the server? Not checking return value of `sendto()`? Is the client socket non-blocking by any chance? When you say "finally read correctly" - do you keep re-sending, or "correct" data just appears with 20 seconds lag? You should post the client code too.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a bit of a guess here.

I can't imagine that your UDP packets wonder around somewhere for 20 seconds. After all RTT around the globe over the public Internet is usually 40 times less then that. So I think you just keep re-sending your data until you get the expected response.

If I am right with my assumption then what you see is a normal UDP **packet loss**. Is that laptop on a wireless link? Does the client app block on some input?

Run `wireshark` on the laptop too. Do you see the same number and sequence of packets as on the sender (server) side? If so, then the client does not consume those packets fast enough. If you actually see the packets back on the client with that 20 second delay then you really have to describe more of your setup to explain the magic :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers..
The problem was that the sendto method was behaving differently on laptop comparing to the desktop.
On laptot sendto was sending 3 UDP packets, on the destop only one.
My application was expecting only one packet,so the processing time + multiply by 3 gives the impression of delay. 
I don't understand why this happens but this was the problem.